# combine coverage reports using istanbul-combine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, code-coverage, istanbul

Let's say I have these coverage reports:

- **/coverage/libs/test/lib1/final-coverage.json**
- **/coverage/libs/test/lib2/final-coverage.json**
- **/coverage/libs/test/lib3/final-coverage.json**

now I would like to combine these reports and generate a html report.

I'm using this **istanbul-combine** to do this kind of work. But it seems as if it couldn't find all these coverage json files and I wonder as why is that.

`istanbul-combine -d coverage/reports -r lcov -r html /coverage/libs/test/**/coverage-final.json`

At the end of the report generation process, it provides me an empty html report.

Answer (score 5):

istanbul-combine [will be deprecated in favor of](https://github.com/jamestalmage/istanbul-combine/issues/2) istanbul report. I did a migration lately.

This was the old configuration that I was using with `istanbul-combine`:

```
istanbul-combine -d coverage -p none -r lcov -r cobertura coverage/hierarchical-grid/coverage-final.json coverage/tree-grid/coverage-final.json coverage/non-grid/coverage-final.json coverage/grid/coverage-final.json
```

Changed to:

```
istanbul report --dir coverage --include coverage/**/coverage-final.json lcov
```

[Related Pull Request.](https://github.com/IgniteUI/igniteui-angular/pull/8843/files#diff-e98936aa52a6dd7416e4296e9628456227d834f7245967383fd9ff80fd985dadR43)

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

So I have found a different way to solve this problem. I wrote a small script, which does the following.

- reads library directory and finds all coverage reports
- reads coverage reports and corrects some incorrect data produced by jest
- merges all reports data into one report
- prints out the final report

**mergeCoverage.js**

```
const fs = require( 'fs-extra');
const glob = require('glob');
const { createReporter } = require('istanbul-api');
const istanbulCoverage = require('istanbul-lib-coverage');

const reporter = createReporter();

/* [ Configuration ] */
const rootDir = './coverage/libs';
const reportOut = './coverage/report';

const normalizeJestCoverage = ( obj ) => {
  const result = { ...obj };

  Object
  .entries( result )
  .filter( ([k, v] ) => v.data )
  .forEach( ([k, v] ) => {
    result[k] = v.data;
  });

  return result;
};

const mergeAllReports = ( coverageMap, reports ) => {
  if ( Array.isArray( reports ) === false ) {
    return;
  }

  reports.forEach( reportFile => {
    const coverageReport = fs.readJSONSync( reportFile );
    coverageMap.merge( normalizeJestCoverage( coverageReport ) );
  })
};

const findAllCoverageReports = ( path, callback ) => {
  glob( path, {}, ( err, reports )=>{
    callback( reports, err );
  });
};

const generateReport = ( coverageMap, types ) => {
  reporter.dir = reportOut;
  reporter.addAll(types || ['html', 'text'] );
  reporter.write( coverageMap );
};

async function main () {
  const coverageMap = istanbulCoverage.createCoverageMap( {} );

  findAllCoverageReports( rootDir + '/**/coverage-final.json', ( reports, err ) => {
    if ( Array.isArray( reports ) ) {
      mergeAllReports( coverageMap, reports );
      generateReport( coverageMap, [ 'text' ]  )
    }
  });
}

main().catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
  process.exit(1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this type of issue when combining multiple package coverage results in a monorepo. I used @skyboyer and @Alexus answer which worked really well and was nice and clean but the dependabot on GitHub came up with an indirect security vulnerability resulting from istanbul use. Using istanbuljs's [nyc](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc) replacement for the istanbul CLI I implemented the same functionality. Unfortunately, it's not nearly as clean but here it is...

I had to rename all of the coverage-final.json files to something unique. Noting my output directory is coverage and the reporter used was json…

```
lerna exec -- 'export WORKING_DIR=$(basename $LERNA_PACKAGE_NAME) && cp ./<output dir>/coverage-final.json ./<output dir>/coverage-final-$(echo $WORKING_DIR).json'
```

After which I needed to place all of those files into a centralized directory…

```
mkdir -p ./coverage && lerna exec -- 'export WORKING_DIR=$(basename $LERNA_PACKAGE_NAME) && cp ./<output dir>/coverage-final-$(echo $WORKING_DIR).json ../../coverage/coverage-final-$(echo $WORKING_DIR).json'
```

This copied the package contents into a root-level directory named coverage. Moving forward, I needed to merge all of the copied results into one json file. For the output directory I used the same coverage directory at the root level…

```
nyc merge ./coverage ./coverage/coverage-final.json
```

And, finally, I needed to transform the result to lcov for input into coveralls (my use-case);

```
nyc report --reporter=lcov --temp-dir=coverage
```

Hope that helps! :-) [Repository containing implementation](https://github.com/ThinkDeepTech/thinkdeep)